# Flutter : why future builder run more than one time

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I have page contain future builder to get username from shared preference :

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ProductProvider>(builder: (context, prod, child) {
      return FutureBuilder(
          future: Services().get_user(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              var name = snapshot.data['name'];
              return OrderDetails(name);
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          });
    });
  }
```

that page have widget contain another future builder depend on name value passed through page :

```
class OrderDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final name;
  const OrderDetails(this.name);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Services().get_orders(name),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          print('snapshot.data.length  ${snapshot.data.length}'); // ------ it is print 6
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text('user_id');
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Services().get_orders(name) method :

```
get_orders(name) async {
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/user/myorder/$name';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return (data);
  }
```

I put data on database which is just this:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "user_id": 24,
  "status": "ordered",
  "order_item": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "order_id": 3,
      "product_id": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "order_id": 3,
      "product_id": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
    }
  ]
}
```

### as a result ,it run 6 times ,and print 'user_id'

Comment: have you used `setState()` inside your  widget anywhere?

Comment: No all are stateless

Comment: can you pls paste full JSON data into your question

Comment: what is the value of `snapshot.data.length`

Comment: that I put is full Json data , and the length read 6

Comment: if the length is 6 then the itemBuilder is supposed to run 6 times. Can you please elaborate Whats exactly the issue for you?

Comment: sorry ,the real length is 1 but it is print 6

Comment: Futurebuilder's builder will most likely run twice - once before the future resolves and once after. You have also wrapped your widget with a provider - is that a change notifier provider? If yes, are you setting something to your provider - that can also trigger a re-build of your widget

Comment: @VinayakaramNagarajan I remove the consumer and still same

Comment: Try to create a variable of type ```Future``` and assinge```Services().get_orders(name)``` to it, and then ```future: youVariableHere```

Answer (score 3):

because it is used inside the build() method.
That's not a problem...if you do not evaluate the Future method inside that.
I mean, you should not do this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Services().get_orders(name),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
 .....
```

but this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _myFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
 .....
```

Where _myFuture is evaluated at initState():

```
class OrderDetails extends StatefullWidget {
@override
_OrderDetailsState createState() => _OrderDetailsState();

}
class _OrderDetailsState extends State<OrderDetails> {

  final name;
  
  Future _myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
     name = widget.name;
     _myFuture = Services().get_orders(name); //this method is async, thus do not slow down the init state: the result is still not ready.
     super.initState();
   }


  const OrderDetails(this.name);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _myFuture,  //the FutureBuilder will wait until the _myFuture will get the results from Services().get_orders(...)
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasFinished ) { //better test: data is always not null. at least with zero data.
          print('snapshot.data.length  ${snapshot.data.length}'); // ------ it is print 6
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text('user_id');
            },
          );
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator(); // a circular progress indicator is the quickest way to tell the user we are waiting for data.
        }
      },
    );
  }
```